# Asynchronus WPF datagrid display data as it is loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, task-parallel-library, wpfdatagrid

I'm not sure which area I'm getting wrong here and could use some help.  I think i'm either not updating the datagrid correctly in the background, or i'm not using the task parallel library correctly.  I'm new to both of these.

I want to see my data load to know that my task is running asynchronously.  While this is just a sample test app in the future this code would be a responsive form for users.

Right now all my data loads at the end of the code being called.  Below is my code.

(please excuse some of the messy naming conventions and error handling as i've been changing a lot of stuff as I read and all i'm focused on is the asynchronous loading of the grid).

```
private void btnRunSearch_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _isSearching = !_isSearching;
    ToggleUIIsSearching(_isSearching);

    _webResults.Add(new WebResult { Description = "test item", DisplayUrl = "www.what?", Title = "Random Preload Title", Url = "www.www.www" });
    dgWebResults.Items.Refresh();

    try
    {
        // Copy the textbox value to a new variable for thread safety.
        string searchTerm = tbSearchTerm.Text;

        Task<List<WebResult>> MyTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<WebResult>>(() =>
            {
                return new WebSearchLogic().GetFilteredResults(searchTerm, SearcherKey);
            });

        Thread.Sleep(4000);

        UpdateDataGrid(MyTask.Result, true);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);


        _webResults.Add(new WebResult { Description = "2test item", DisplayUrl = "2www.what?", Title = "2Random Preload Title", Url = "2www.www.www" });
        dgWebResults.Items.Refresh();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        tbSearchTerm.Text = ae.Flatten().Message;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tbSearchTerm.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}


private void UpdateDataGrid(List<WebResult> newItems, bool append)
{
    if (!append)
    {
        _webResults.Clear();
    }

    foreach (WebResult wr in newItems)
    {
        _webResults.Add(wr);
    }

    dgWebResults.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Basically I want to see the first test item appear, then see the other results appear, then finally see the 2nd test item appear.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Sincerely,
Adam Heeg

Comment: What you need is as the processing is done in the background / async, the data grid should keep updating with data, right now it updates in the end after all the processing is done. Essentially it should get incrementally updated

Comment: I would use a BackgroundWorker with WorkerReportsProgress.  You can pass an object in progress.  Then just add it to an ObservableCollection you bind to.

Comment: Check out the following link, it has the solution of the exact thing you need:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535749/support-of-progress-reporting-and-incremental-results-in-net-4-0-task-parallel

Task doesn't have any direct replacement of BackgroundWorker

Comment: In above link check this part, it has the exact code to do it using Task

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8518258/1559611

Comment: Thank you for your help.